# Page displaying class is not behaving well

Tags: php, mysql, class

For a simple cms I am working on i built a class to display articles inside defined pages.

What i want for example: index.php?page=1 it will display all articles matching page_id 1.

So far it works, it will display all articles with page_id 1, but for page_id 2 it does not work. A record with page_id 2 exists at the db table.

Class:

```
    include_once('./includes/config.php');
class Content {


public $id;
public $page_id;
public $title;
public $content;
public $position;



var $conn;

function Content()
        {
                $this->conn = mysql_connect(Config::DB_HOST, Config::DB_USER, Config::DB_PASS);
                mysql_select_db(Config::DB_NAME, $this->conn);
        }


function disp_page_articles($page)
{
    $sql = 
"       SELECT 
           id
,              page_id
,              title
,              content
,              date
,              position 
    FROM 
           articles 
    WHERE 
           page_id = $page 
    ORDER BY 
           id
,              position";

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn) or die(mysql_error());

   if(!$result){
       return array();
   }




    while($article = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){





    $content .= '
        <div class="blok">
        <h2>
        </br>
        '.$article['title'].'</h2>
        </br>
        '.$article['content'].'
        </br>
        '.$article['date'].'
        </div>
    ';

   } 
    return $content;
}

}
```

Running the class:

```
include("classes/content.class.php");


$content = "";
$content = new Content();
$page = $_GET['page'];

echo $content->disp_page_articles($page); 

echo "<p>Page ID: ". $_GET['page']."</p>";
```

Did i forget something here?

Comment: Echo out the SQL you're generating, and run it in the database - does it find the record you're looking for? Do you get any errors when you run the query? Does mysql_query find no records, or is it finding them but not returning anything anyway?

Comment: How do you mean that? Can you give me an example for that? I tried but it does not work

Comment: An example for what? What did you try?

Comment: i echoed the sql and it didnt show up. I also echoed the $page and it contains the proper id given

Comment: I just ran your code through a mock db I created and there does not seem to be any issues except for some variables not be initialized/ could you elaborate further on the exact issue your have does the second table have the page_id set to 2

Comment: Where did you add the echo? Just before the mysql_query call? If you've got a class doing the page rendering, the content might not show up where you'd expect.

Comment: I added it before the mysql_query now, this is the output: SELECT id , page_id , title , content , date , position FROM articles WHERE page_id = '2' ORDER BY id , position - Nothing unusual imho

Test page at http://jediah.nl/pgwe/testcontent.php?page=2 by the way, try ?page=1 for a "working" example

Comment: @jediah - that does look fine. Now, what happens when you run that directly in the database, through PHPMyAdmin or whatever - does that find the right record? You can also check to see whether $result contains anything after the query, and what you're returning from your function.

Comment: Also - if your query doesn't find anything, you're returning an empty array; if it does, you're returning a string. Is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: Ok, i executed the query inside phpMyAdmin and it works (with 2 as page_id)

I also echoed $result that will give me "Resource id #5" (dont know what that means)

and yes, that is what to be expected (empty array)

Comment: @jediah - the Resource id is fine - it's a reference to the database statement. Can you try echoing out $content, too? Before, after, and in the middle of the while loop? I can't see any reason why it shouldn't be returning anything.

Comment: $content does not exist before the while loop, only options will be in the middle and after so i did. Result: still returning content of page_id 1 where page_id 2 remains empty..

Comment: @jediah - when you call your function with `$page` of 2, is anything being assigned to `$content`? Is the while loop running at all? (Also, if you use '@andrewsi' in your comment, I'll get a note that you've replied, and you won't have to wait for me to remember to check the question for an update)

Comment: @andrewsi Even if i add "2" to the query it won't display.. if something else would be assigned to $content, would page_id 1 show up?

Comment: @jediah - it shouldn't, no. All I can suggest is a few more debugging statements. echo out `$page` to make sure your function is being called with the right parameter; echo out `$sql` to make sure it's being passed the correct value and is correctly formed; and echo out `$content` before it's returned to make sure that it's returning what it should. One of those three should produce something unexpected!

Comment: @jediah - try a print_r($content->disp_page_articles($page)); rather than echo or a var_dump( $content->disp_page_articles($page)); as these return better information.

Comment: @unasAquila I added a var_dump and it returns a NULL, print_r does nothing

Comment: @jediah - could you show you db structure in your question use the mysql export.

Comment: @unasAquila http://pastebin.com/7LDeQUxF

Comment: @jediah - i have added you exact code no changes and the database you linked http://www.codeinstone.com/jediah/?page=2 and it works perfectly so your issue has to be somewhere ele.

Comment: @unasAquila, this is very weird..

Comment: @jediah - did you say that the function returns a NULL when you're passing a 2 into it? That would imply that it's not going into the loop at all. Can you add the results of `var_dump($result)` and `var_dump($sql)` to your question? You'll need to add both lines just before the start of the `while` loop.

Comment: @andrewsi Ok, i did what you suggested. See the result for yourself: http://jediah.nl/pgwe/testcontent.php?page=2

Comment: @jediah - the only thing I can see that would explain that is if there's no data for page 2 in the database.

Comment: @andrewsi That's very strange, because it is really in there..

Comment: @jediah - it's the only thing I can think of. Your function isn't returning an empty array, so the query is fine; but it is returning NULL. Since you're not initializing `$content` anywhere, it will return NULL only if you've not ever going into the while loop. And it'll only do that if there's no data retrieved. And yet the exact query it's generating works in MySQL.

Comment: I guess it could be something to do with row-level permissions on the table, but that really does seem unlikely. So I'm going to have to admit that I'm stumped.

Comment: @andrewsi I don't know what happened since the last time i checked but the class seems to work now.. very strange. I want to thank you very much for your help! You helped me a lot!!

Comment: @jediah - I'm glad you managed to get it sorted out. Even if we still don't know why :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 
           page_id = $page
```

Should be

```
WHERE 
           page_id = '$page'
```

Comment: doesn't need to be if the column type is integer

Comment: As long as $page is INT it doesn't matter, I guess?

Comment: I had on case like this a time ago. So i offred the solution>. !! :)..It may help

Comment: This does not make any change